# Zend Framework comm-app cannot find class

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm following [this](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=C52lb35EiygC&pg=PT96&lpg=PT96&dq=%3C?php%20namespace%20Users%5CController;%20use%20Zend%5CMvc%5CController%5CAbstractActionController;%20use%20Zend%5CView%5CModel%5CViewModel;%20use%20Users%5CForm%5CRegisterForm;%20class%20RegisterController%20extends%20AbstractActionController%20%7B&source=bl&ots=3l1KrCBe9v&sig=Jtq52lcR-9_BtV6J6vv1YS3bApA&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=SfGdUqeaMtTMsATMhIHIAQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%3C?php%20namespace%20Users%5CController;%20use%20Zend%5CMvc%5CController%5CAbstractActionController;%20use%20Zend%5CView%5CModel%5CViewModel;%20use%20Users%5CForm%5CRegisterForm;%20class%20RegisterController%20extends%20AbstractActionController%20%7B&f=false) book, and I'm in chapter 3 and this code is returning me the following error: Fatal error: Class 'Users\Model\User' not found in /var/www/CommunicationApp/module/Users/src/Users/Controller/RegisterController.php on line 70

I want to know what is wrong with the code, or if it's not the code than what is it?

```
<?php
namespace Users\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Users\Form\RegisterForm;
use Users\Form\RegisterFilter;

use Users\Model\User;
use Users\Model\UserTable;

class RegisterController extends AbstractActionController
{

public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new RegisterForm();
    $viewModel  = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form)); 
    return $viewModel; 
}

public function processAction()
{
    if (!$this->request->isPost()) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array( 
                    'controller' => 'register', 
                    'action' =>  'index' 
                ));
    }

    $post = $this->request->getPost();

    $form = new RegisterForm();
    $inputFilter = new RegisterFilter();
    $form->setInputFilter($inputFilter);

    $form->setData($post);
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        $model = new ViewModel(array(
            'error' => true,
            'form'  => $form,
        ));
        $model->setTemplate('users/register/index');
        return $model;
    }

    // Create user
    $this->createUser($form->getData());

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute(NULL , array( 
                    'controller' => 'register', 
                    'action' =>  'confirm' 
                ));
}

public function confirmAction()
{
    $viewModel  = new ViewModel(); 
    return $viewModel; 
}

protected function createUser(array $data)
{

    $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

    $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype (new \Users\Model\User); //line 70
    $tableGateway = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('user' /* table name  */, $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

    $user = new User();
    $user->exchangeArray($data);

    $userTable = new UserTable($tableGateway);
    $userTable->saveUser($user);

    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: try **new \Users\Model\User** instead **new User**

Comment: Remi Thomas check the line 70 - $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype (new \Users\Model\User); It's like you said, and that what is causing the problem I think

Comment: is the namespace and classname in the user model class correct?

Comment: yes, it is correct - namespace Users\Model;

class User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a correct autoloading check if the model file is in the following directory
`/module/Users/src/Users/Model/User.php`

if is not zend can't autoload your model file and that triggers your error if (as you pointed out your classname and namespace in the model file is correct) the file is not placed there.

Comment: /module/Users/src/Users/Model/User.php check, that's not the problem

Comment: wow that was a fast answere - in my eyes you make all correct
- correct namespace
- correct classname
- correct file location

Comment: check ``new \Users\Model\User()`` not ``new \Users\Model\User``

Comment: It's 100% equal to the book, I tried using User() but I'm getting the same error

Comment: wait a sec - i test it by myself

Comment: something is wrong with your autoloading or posted code above - i cant reproduce your error - all works in my zf2 test class when u obey all steps in my post/comments - what is your zf2 version number?

Comment: It's the ZendServer-6.2.0

Comment: i mean the ZF2 version of the framework- check if the latest stable version with is currently ``2.2.5`` if necessary update to this one